# ES6 block scoping with in switch

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

In ES6, I can achieve block scoping per case:

```
switch(somVar){
    case 'first': 
    {
        let itemId='foo'; 
    }
    break; 
    case 'second': 
    { 
        let itemId='bar'; 
    } 
}
```

Obviously, `itemId` might as well be declared on top.
For my use case, locally scoped variables make more sense because in my overall code, it is more easily identifiable what's happening, and there are a number of `case`'s, whereas some blocks contain the variable in question and others don't.

I have't seen block scoping used for `switch/case` as common usage.
My question is simply, whether there are reasons not to do it, stylistic-wise or else.

Edit, updated example code to avoid confusion:

```
const someFunc(action) => { 
    switch(action.type){ 
        case 'first': 
        { 
            let itemId=action.someObj.someProp.id; 
            //Do something with itemId
        } 
        break; 
        case 'second': 
        { 
            let itemId=action.someObj.someProp.id; 
            //Do something with itemId
        } 
        break; 
        case 'third': 
            //No use of itemId 
    } 
}
```

itemId could be declared at the top, but I'd prefer to look at the property per case. There doesn't appear to be an immediate reason to share the variable across different cases. It would also appear to be nonsense to 'invent' a different name for what is essentially the same.

This could probably be written differently, but this example is a common pattern in Flux architecture.

Comment: Most of the times, a variable is created before `switch` and returned/used after `switch` depending on the case.

Comment: I don't see any reason not to do this. This is the whole point of block-level scoping. You just need to make sure you create blocks for your `case`s, otherwise you might try to **define the same variable twice** in the `switch block`, causing a syntax error.

Comment: I'd say there are two large reasons for it not being common usage: 1) you couldn't do it pre-ES6; 2) situations where it's useful don't come up too often. There's no reason why you shouldn't do it.

Comment: @Tushar I agree. However in my use case, I have a variety of cases that sometimes perform action on variables that are similar (hence would have the same name), but often also on entirely different variables. It is within the scope of action creators / reducers with Flux/Redux. It appears to make more sense to 'encapsulate' local variables without needing to care for the outside scope.

Comment: "I have a variety of cases that sometimes perform action on variables that are similar (hence would have the same name)" I have to state the obvious but why does logic need to be *in* the switch statement? That would break my head and I would need PTSD therapy. Better. Put the logic into functions with an intention reveling name and call the function from your switch statement.

Comment: @Sukima When an object is passed to the function that handles the switch statement, there can be nested attributes that are more easy to work with when storing in a local variable, rather than to write the entire 'path'. I would prefer to use 'let' per case to explicitly declare. There is no certaint which case uses which attributes of the object passed in. Perhaps this is clearer. If there is compelling reason not to, I of course like to hear.

Comment: I like this syntax. You could even put the opening braces in the same line like the colon and the break statement within the block.

Comment: I would bet money that you do not need a switch statement. They are code smells for a reason. Feel free to toss up the code in a gist.github.com and I'll probably find a refactoring that removes the switch statement.

Comment: I think it's ok to do it e.g. for some intermediate calculation/statement that is only required in a certain `switch` statement. Otherwise I can't think of anything right now where it would make sense. I don't get the use case that you explained like "perform action on entirely different variables"... what use would a `switch` statement have when it changes variables that are declared in and gone after the switch statement?

Comment: Use case is when a generic action is dispatched, where attributes are added to the object passed (the action). The switch case handles different action identifiers (string constants), but the attributes may vary across different actions.

Comment: Ok but that is not performing an action on different variables, but different properties. I just read your reply to Sukima's comment and I would not suggest to create copies of properties to work with and then write them back to the object, as it complicates reading your code later. Keep in mind that you can create references to properties that are objects but not to primitive type properties (see https://jsfiddle.net/L20nv4qs/)

Answer (score 2):

Abstract the logic into functions. Switch statements by themselves are difficult to read let alone a bunch of logic and variable scoping. It is much better to abstract the logic into functions. Also after abstracting to functions you will probably notice that there isn't much need for a switch statement all together. See [Avoid use of switch statements](https://github.com/DockYard/styleguides/blob/master/engineering/javascript.md#conditional-statements) section of the DockYard style guides.

```
function handleFirstCase() {
  var itemId = 'foo';
  // Do stuff with itemId
  return expectedValue;
}

function handleSecondCase() {
  var itemId = 'bar';
  // Do stuff with itemId
  return expectedValue;
}

let result;
switch(somVar){
case 'first':
  result = handleFirstCase();
  break;
case 'second':
  result = handleSecondCase();
  break;
}
```

Notice how the switch statement becomes one line. This can easily be distilled to a dictionary lookup instead:

```
const CASES = {
  first() {
    var itemId = 'foo';
    // Do stuff with itemId
    return expectedValue;
  },

  second() {
    var itemId = 'bar';
    // Do stuff with itemId
    return expectedValue;
  }
};

let result = CASES[someVar]();
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem occures due to switch scenario is handled as a single block, irrespective of the individual case statments, as the 'break' statement is optional.

Rewriting your code to the following should do the job:

```
const someFunc(action) => { 
    if (action.type == 'first'){ 
        let itemId=action.someObj.someProp.id; 
        //Do something with itemId
    } 
    else if (action.type == 'second'){  
        let itemId=action.someObj.someProp.id; 
        //Do something with itemId
    } 
    else { //Third  
        //No use of itemId 
    } 
}
```