# Destructuring in switch statement gives 'variable is not initialized' error

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop, destructuring, object-destructuring

```
let chosen = 3;
    let myFriends = [
      { title: "Osama", age: 39, available: false, skills: ["HTML", "CSS"] },
      { title: "Ahmed", age: 25, available: false, skills: ["Python", "Django"] },
      { title: "Sayed", age: 33, available: true, skills: ["PHP", "Laravel"] },
    ];

    // let [x,y,z]=myFriends;
    // let {title:ft,age:fag,available:fav,skills:[,fskill]}=x;
    // let {title:st,age:sag,available:sav,skills:[,sskill]}=y;
    // let {title:tt,age:tag,available:tav,skills:[,tskill]}=z;

    switch (chosen) {
      case 1:
        let [d]=myFriends;
        let {title,age,available,skills:[,skill]}=d;
        console.log(title);
        console.log(age);
        console.log(available?"available":"notAvailable");
        console.log(skill);
        break;
      case 2:
        [,d,]=myFriends;
        ({title,age,available,skills:[,skill]}=d);
        console.log(title);
        console.log(age);
        console.log(available?"available":"notAvailable");
        console.log(skill);
        break;
      case 3:
        [,,d]=myFriends;
        ({title,age,available,skills:[,skill]}=d);
        console.log(title);
        console.log(age);
        console.log(available?"available":"notAvailable");
        console.log(skill);
        break;
      
    }
```

I tried to change variables name , but every time it tells me that variable is not intialized (I mean variable (d) ) and tells me that variables (title , age skills) cann`t be reached

Comment: Toy have to declare your variables one every block because variables are block-scoped and if one case runs the other don't so variables are not declared in other cases. Just add `let` before the other variables as well

Comment: ...or create a block for each `case`: `case 1: { let d /* ... */ }`. Though, in this particular example, you should simply use `myFriends[d - 1]` instead of `switch`/`case`.

Comment: this issue happens because of of the scope of the variables in `switch-case`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ES6 block scoping with in switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38828898/es6-block-scoping-with-in-switch)

Comment: also [switch statement and scopes in ES2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39001827/switch-statement-and-scopes-in-es2015)

Answer (score 2):

Declaring the variables within each switch case did not work for me when destructuring data.
However, it works to declare the variables as common to all the switch cases.

```
let chosen = 3;
    let myFriends = [
    { title: "Osama", age: 39, available: false, skills: ["HTML", "CSS"] },
    { title: "Ahmed", age: 25, available: false, skills: ["Python", "Django"] },
    { title: "Sayed", age: 33, available: true, skills: ["PHP", "Laravel"] },
    ];

    // let [x,y,z]=myFriends;
    // let {title:ft,age:fag,available:fav,skills:[,fskill]}=x;
    // let {title:st,age:sag,available:sav,skills:[,sskill]}=y;
    // let {title:tt,age:tag,available:tav,skills:[,tskill]}=z;
    let d;
    let title,age,available,skill;

    switch (chosen) {
    case 1:
        [d]=myFriends;
        ({title,age,available,skills:[,skill]}=d);
        console.log(title);
        console.log(age);
        console.log(available?"available":"notAvailable");
        console.log(skill);
        break;
    case 2:
        [,d,]=myFriends;
        ({title,age,available,skills:[,skill]}=d);
        console.log(title);
        console.log(age);
        console.log(available?"available":"notAvailable");
        console.log(skill);
        break;
    case 3:
        [,,d]=myFriends;
        ({title,age,available,skills:[,skill]}=d);
        console.log(title);
        console.log(age);
        console.log(available?"available":"notAvailable");
        console.log(skill);
        break;
    }
```